# Query with SQL Server 2008 R2 with FireDAC

Tags: sql-server, delphi, sql-server-2008-r2, firedac, delphi-10-seattle

I'm new to Firedac but not with Delphi

I can make a connection with SQL Server, and when I connect, there is no problem. I get connection OK. It works with code, with the wizard and with the FireDAC explorer.

The name of the database is :

```
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\3410b539-431f-4dff-ad0d-a574d1b13498.MDF
```

I'm stuck with a simple query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Account;
```

This query works from within the FireDac explorer but not from my program, I'm getting the following error:

> [FireDAC][Phys][ODBC][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Could not find server 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.'

I'm also also getting the same error, when I try to do it from the UI within Delphi.

To try the query, I dropped onto the form a TFDQuery, the connection property was set automatically to the unique connection on the form. Then I set the query with the query editor, I get the error when I click on execute.

With code it like this :

```
FDConnection1.Connected := true;
FDQuery1.Close;
FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from Account;';
FDQuery1.Active := True;
```

When I debug the program, I get the error when setting the query active.

I see that the name of the DB is not complete in the error message. But it's complete in the component settings

Please advise,

---

I tried some extra test :
If I run the query from the UI editor (double-clicking on the FDConnection, Tab SQL Script), type the query, it works :-).

But when I try to do it on the FDQuery component, with the connection assigned to previous FDConnection, I get the same error. It' like some parameters are missing.

Comment: Sorry Delphi "Seattle".
It works, without problem in the UI with an ADOConnetion + ADOQuery.

Mmmm must I think to switch to ADO. What is the best for speed, facility.. ?
What do you think ?

Comment: "What do you think ?"  FireDAC *seems* fine, but I prefer the "safety in numbers" of ADO (I mean numbers of ADO users generally, not just Delphi ones) for getting problems fixed.  FireDAC is very good, for a one-man effort, until you run into a problem with it, in which case its code and degree of abstraction can be impenetrable.  The author is quite active on the EMB NGs, though.

Comment: How are you configuring your FireDAC connection? You've provided no information regarding that, and you've not even explained where (or how) you're executing the `SELECT`. *It's complete in the component settings* isn't really useful.

Comment: Why are you using the filename as Database name? Normally when connection to a MS SQL  you provide the name (DNS or ip) of the server, the username and password. Then Database name would be just the name of the database not the filename of the database

Comment: Here is a connection string for my SQL Server 

Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=pass1234;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=MOWD;Data Source=Dellserver

As you see the Databasename (Initial Catalog) is MOWD not the filename of the MOWD databse

Comment: Well, I didn't choose those databases name, it's the former programmer who chosed them :-( I'm just inherit from the system.

Comment: @Ydakilux try to do as I showed you

Comment: I tried with ADOConnection It work like a charm with the following connection string .

Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=MyPassWord;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myuser;Initial Catalog=C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\3410b539-431f-4dff-ad0d-a574d1b13498.MDF;Data Source=SQLSRV\REGULUS;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=PROGRAMMATION;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False

But with Firedac it's not a connection string.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the location of the SQL data file, instead of the name of the SQL Database.

If you do not know the name you can use the wizard to try and find it.

(Sorry could not add comments yet.  This is also mentioned by Jens in the comments)

Update: if that is really the name, try enclosing it in [ ].

Comment: As I said in previous comment, that's really the database name. The former programmer choosed filename like a filepath. That's the name I see when I use the wizard  and when I use the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Enclose the database name in [ ]

Answer (score 0):

I got this response from an Embarcadero engineer:

> The problem is not in FireDAC, but in SQL Server ODBC driver
>   SQLPrimaryKeys function. It fails to work with a catalog name
>   containing a dot. FireDAC uses this function to get primary key fields
>   for a result set, when fiMeta is included into FetchOptions.Items. So,
>   as a workaround / solution, please exclude fiMeta from
>   FetchOptions.Items.